# Google managed vm java - 503 response code

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We have a running application on gae java flexi env,
now a days we are getting 503 errors most frequently for most of the urls -

response code - 503
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.

What could be possible reason ?

Comment: anything else in the logs?

Comment: This is what every log for this error shows -

Comment: 2016-06-26 02:31:22.986 /book/hotels/india/kottayam/near-airport-railway-station-bus-stand/hotel-breeze-land-00038847_02 503 6ms 0kb instance=0 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) module=default version=6-3-14
162.158.72.107 - - [25/Jun/2016:14:01:22 -0700] "GET /book/hotels/india/kottayam/near-airport-railway-station-bus-stand/hotel-breeze-land-00038847_02 HTTP/1.1" 503 0 - " Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"  ms=6 cpu_ms=0 instance=0 app_engine_release=1.9.38 
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.

Comment: any help is really required